# Element type is invalid errors in React

Tags: reactjs

I have created simple react app where I have defined four components such as App.js, AppHeader.js, AppFooter.js, AppHome.js. I have imported AppHeader , AppFooter and AppHomem into App.And when I run npm start to check the output I am getting the below error.

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Below is the respective code. Please check this and help me where am I missing.

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AppHeader from './AppHeader.js'
import AppFooter from './AppFooter.js'
import AppHome from './AppHome.js'

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
      <AppHeader />
      <AppHome />
      <AppFooter />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Navbar} from 'react-bootstrap';

class AppFooter extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Navbar inverse fixed="bottom">
      <Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Brand>
          &copy; AV Illusions
        </Navbar.Brand>
      </Navbar.Header>
    </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

export default AppFooter;
```

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Jumbotron,Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

class AppHome extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Jumbotron>
        <h1>Ciao , Leute!</h1>
        <p>
        Place to boost up yourself
        </p>
        <p>
        <Button variant="primary">Learn more</Button>
        </p>
        </Jumbotron>
    );
  }
}

export default AppHome;
```

Comment: The error means exactly what it says. An import you expected to be a component isn't there. It's impossible to say what's wrong because not all imports are present. There's no AppHeader. It's not known what are module names and how they are related. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's even not known what line the error refers to.

Comment: Full error is as below.

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `AppHeader`.
▶ 29 stack frames were collapsed.
Module../src/index.js
D:/secret/secretapp/src/index.js:8
  5 | import './index.css';
  6 | import App from './components/App';
  7 | 
> 8 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
  9 |

Comment: this is the code index.js

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: The error says that the error is caused by AppHeader. It doesn't present in the question.

Comment: Please share the code of AppHeader.js too.

Also, use [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) while writing code in comments.

Comment: I have fixed issue by reformatting the code . Thank you everyone for your help